# Override user register default URL to set up password

Tags: users

in order to create a sign in/sign up workflow on a decoupled Drupal(React on front).
I've used the core provided rest resource `/user/register` with Rest ui, and after giving the permission Access POST on User registration resource to anonymous users , i was able to register users via the resouce `/user/register?_format=hal_json` without any authentication

**I wonder if there is a way to override the link that is by default sent to the newly users via mail to setup his password ?**

I don't want the users to setup their passwords on a Drupal page with a Drupal form.

Answer (score 1):

> I think no need to override the default register url.

To prevent Anonymous from register users, Just go ***Administration >> Configuration  People*** http://example.com/admin/config/people/accounts.
and check **Administrators only** in **REGISTRATION AND CANCELLATION** fieldset like the following:

[image]

If you have another raison to change the default url follow this [tutorial](https://www.berramou.com/blog/drupal-8-how-change-default-userlogin-path) just change route name from `user.login` to `user.register`.